# Multiple SplitViewControllers in iPad Application

Tags: ipad, ios, uiwindow

We are creating an iPad application that uses multiple SplitViewController.  From the Apple documentation I understand that the SplitViewController needs to be the rootViewController of the window.

Does anyone have any experience or suggestions on how to create a navigation scheme that switches between multiple SplitViewControllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems that this is not a supported design.  We have since decided to use one SplitViewController at the root, and swap out it's views when the screen changes.  This seems to work pretty well.